# How to properly pass functions as props to child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a function that I want to pass to the a child that is two levels deep. My function is :

```
const addToTrip= (isChecked, coordinates, title, yelpID)=>{
  console.log("added to trip ")
  if(isChecked){
    setWaypoints((waypoints)=>[...waypoints, {name:title, yelp_id:yelpID, coordinates:coordinates}])
  } else if(!isChecked){
    const newWaypoints = waypoints.filter((waypoint)=>waypoint.yelp_id !== yelpID)
    setWaypoints(newWaypoints)
  }
}
```

My function is used in my `Businesses` component and it is rendered under certain conditions

```
{hikes.length>0 && (
     <Businesses
       hikes = {hikes}
       addToTrip = {addToTrip}
     />
)}
```

When I initially run my app and `hikes` is empty, I thought my function isnt supposed to be invoked until I call it, but it is being called because my `waypoints` state gets set twice and my `console.log("added to trip ")` triggers twice as well.

I tried to go about it with changing my render logic of `Businesses` to

```
{hikes.length>0 && (
       <Businesses
            hikes = {hikes}
            // addToTrip = {addToTrip}
            addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip}  
       />
)}
```

With the above code, I dont actually get my console log statements and my `waypoints` state remain untouched. Now the issue with this is I cant seem to use this function in my child component properly like I was able to in my first approach. I know that I am calling the `addToTrip` function successfully as my console.log will print as expected, but it's not detecting my input parameters any more.

Here is my first child component:

```
export const Businesses = (props)=>{
    const {hikes, addToTrip} = props
    return(<>
    <div className="businessesColumn">
    {hikes.map(hike=>(
        <BusinessCard ...
         />
)}
```

Here is my second child component:

```
export const BusinessCard = (props)=>{

    const {img, title, location, description, star, reviewCount, addToTrip, coordinates, yelpID} = props;
        
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(isChecked)
        addToTrip(isChecked, coordinates, title, yelpID)
    },[isChecked])
    const handleOnChange = ()=>{
        setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    }
    return (...)
```

Q1: How come my function is called even when I am not calling it when I am passing it as `addToTrip = {addToTrip}`? I know react creates the function on every render, unless I usecallback, but is it suppose to "call" it?

Q2: How am I able to pass parameters from child component if I were to pass function as props with  `addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip}`

Q3: Does React create a new `addToTrip` object for each component it is passed to? Ive noticed that my `addToTrip` gets called for each component that requires it but doesnt even call it

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try changing your console.log in addToTrip and add on the parameters so changing it into `console.log("added to trip", isChecked, coordinates, title, yelpID)` and seeing if that works?

Comment: Q1 `addToTrip = {addToTrip}` is definitely not invoking `addToTrip`. It is likely being called somewhere down the node tree. Q2 you probably don't want to use `addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip} `: it would mean you have to eventually call it like this (`addToTrip()()`) which you probably don't want. If you have to pipe the function through a large number of components, I would probably use a React Context like the current answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: How come my function is called even when I am not calling it when I am passing it as addToTrip = {addToTrip}? I know react creates the function on every render, unless I usecallback, but is it suppose to "call" it?

It actually does not trigger your function but passes down to child components only. In this context, you don't need to call `useCallback`, because your function is never modified.

> Q2: How am I able to pass parameters from child component if I were to pass function as props with addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip}

`addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip}` is not a proper way to call your function. It should be

- `addToTrip = {()=>addToTrip()}` (it will create a new function every time the component gets re-rendered). In this case, you can call `useCalback` to memoize your function
- `addToTrip = {addToTrip}` (it won't create a new function but re-use the current function)

> Q3: Does React create a new addToTrip object for each component it is passed to? Ive noticed that my addToTrip gets called for each component that requires it but doesnt even call it

The problem is from `useEffect`. When your component get rendered, `useEffect` will be triggered initially, and `addToTrip(isChecked, coordinates, title, yelpID)` will get called. For the fix, you should move `addToTrip` to `handleOnChange` which is only triggered when you tick on checkboxes

```
const handleOnChange = ()=>{
   setIsChecked(!isChecked);
   addToTrip(!isChecked, coordinates, title, yelpID);
}
```

Comment: This Q2 and Q3 analysis is very good. Nesting addToTrip on handleOnChange seems like a good idea if handleOnChange is configured correctly!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and solution!! So I was under the impression that anything that depends on the value of a `state` eg side effects, should be handled by `useEffect` Im assuming that is not always the best approach. Could you briefly explain when each approach should be used? ty

Comment: @benwl I personally use `useEffect` when I have multiple dependencies when my logic depends on multiple states' changes. The second `useEffect` usage is when you want to listen to props' changes. For example, if your `isChecked` is a prop (not an internal state) and we don't know when it's updated from a prop (on a parent component), so in this case, `useEffect` will be the best for you

Answer (score 1):

I can tell in this case that it may not be extremely relevant. But, if you have a huge state tree logic where you would need the same state being passed down from a grandfather component (parent of a parent) to a grandchild (child of a child), then React has a context that helps [React JS Context Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

For Q1, I believe addToTrip is accurate since you are passing down the function reference (as opposed to passing down something like addToTrip()).